# Should questions contain the name of the work being asked about in the title?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was wondering if I should always mention the name of the work I'm asking about in the title of a question.

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but definitely related: [Is it OK for titles to have tags in them?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/is-it-ok-for-titles-to-have-tags-in-them)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's optional to include name of the work in a question title, but it needs to be in the question's body.

Don't forget to tag appropriately, we traditionally have work-specific tags, and often franchise tags as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are no general site wider rules I'm aware of (nor, frankly, any reason to bother adding them).

My rule of thumb is: add work name in the title if the following is true:

- The question wording is generic enough that I can apply to a multitude of works
- The question title isn't already too long and in need of shortening

Otherwise, I skip. The reason to skip is that most people viewing the questions would see the first tag (which is typically the work name) right next to the title anyway.